# Apple script are not working in macos 13(Ventura) for automatically navigate users to system preferences privacy

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-ventura

Apple script are not working in macos 13(Ventura) for automatically navigate users to system preferences privacy

```
tell application "System Settings"
    --get a reference to the Security & Privacy preferences pane
    set securityPane to pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
    
    --tell that pane to navigate to its "Accessibility" section under its Privacy tab
    --(the anchor name is arbitrary and does not imply a meaningful hierarchy.)
    tell securityPane to reveal anchor "Privacy_Accessibility"
    
    --open the preferences window and make it frontmost
    activate
end tell
```

it's working on old mac os version

i try this following apple script.

````
tell application "System Settings"
    tell pane id "com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility" to anchor
    activate
end tell

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tell application "System Settings"
    --get a reference to the Security & Privacy preferences pane
    set securityPane to pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
    
    --tell that pane to navigate to its "Accessibility" section under its Privacy tab
    --(the anchor name is arbitrary and does not imply a meaningful hierarchy.)
    tell securityPane to reveal anchor "Privacy_Accessibility"
    
    --open the preferences window and make it frontmost
    activate
end tell```
````